# As hyphen every 4 characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I am needing to add a hyphen every 4 characters in a string using JavaScript. I found some similiar demos but didn't really understand them enough to modify them for this.

Currently I have:

```
 reg = hex_md5(document.forms["grform"]["category4"].value);
```

Reg is the string I need to add a hyphen to every 4 chrs. E.G 12345678 would be 1234-5678

MTIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dashedReg = reg.replace(/(....)(?=.)/g, "$1-");
```

"Replace every occurence of four characters with the same sequence and a dash, only if they are followed by a character (i.e. not at end of string)"

Comment: @jfriend00: It will not, because of the positive lookahead guaranteeing that each replaced sequence needs to have a character after it; thus, last four characters would not match.

Comment: Better use `(.{4})(?=.)`

Comment: @TusharGupta: `....` is equivalent, and has the same character count as `.{4}`. I don't think either is better than the other.

Comment: yeah i know they are equal .But it looks good with compact code.

Comment: @TusharGupta: ... so, 4 characters of `.{4}` are somehow more compact than 4 characters of `....`?

Comment: This works great for adding colons into MAC addresses!  Thanks!   

`var ipNumberColons = ipNumber.replace(/(..)(?=.)/g, "$1:");`